# How to detect tab/spaces in canonical path in Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, path, swt

Let's say I have this path entered in "`myTextField`": `/home/extras /myFolder`

This is the if statement I have, it works perfectly on Linux, it detects the space between `extras` and `/` but Windows does't detect the space after each directory name.

Something curious is that Windows detects the spaces in between the directory name, for example if I enter: `ex tras` , but it never detects the spaces at the end. Something to do with Windows, but how to solve it?

```
if (new File(myTextField.getText()).getCanonicalPath().contains(" ")) {
//DO STUFF
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with SWT? I would guess `getCanonicalPath` is removing trailing blanks on Windows, this method does behave differently on different platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Windows normalizes file names by removing trailing spaces and periods, see "[File path formats on Windows systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats#trim-characters)". Additionally the Java APIs do not permit skipping this normalization by appending a trailing directory separator (`\`), the trailing separator is simply ignored.

This explains why the trailing space is removed by `getCanonicalPath()`, but the space in the middle of the file name is not removed.